# Why is my GET request not being sent using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to send a JSON string through a GET request from one system to another, using the PHP cURL library. Then I am trying to send back a JSON string from the second machine, back to the first machine.

**The problem is that apparently, nothing is being sent from the first to the second machine, because when I run the PHP script in the first machine in the browser, the screen is blank**.

How should I fix this?

***Script in the first machine:***

```
<?php 

    $extractedDataArray = array(
        "DataFiles/datum.txt3" => "60340039" 
        );

    $extractedDataJson = json_encode($extractedDataArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    $url = "http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/TestTwo/index.php";

    $result = json_decode(sendJsonByGet($url, $extractedDataJson));

    echo $result;





    function sendJsonByGet($url="http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/TestTwo/index.php", $extractedDataJson) {
        $curlObject = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $extractedDataJson);
        curl_setopt($curlObject, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt(   $curlObject, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($extractedDataJson) )   );

        $result = curl_exec($curlObject);

        curl_close($curlObject);

        return $result;

    }
```

***Script in the Second Machine:***

```
<?php 

$dataJson = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo "Test Test Test<br><br>";

echo "RESULT RETURNED FROM AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD: $dataJson";

?>
```

Comment: turning on error. Write `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` in your script and see if you getting any error

Comment: @B.Desai No I am not getting anything on the screen :s